# How would I write my own new format specifier in C?

Tags: c, format, specifier

Is it possible to write a new format specifier in C? For example, let's say, %g is a format specifier which prints the ip address in A.B.C.D format from the unsigned integer equivalent.

```
int ip_addr = Some integer

printf("ip address = %g", ip_addr);
```

output: prints ip address in A.B.C.D format

Comment: You can write whatever you want in [tag:c], but you can't add a format specifier to the standard library function `printf()`. You can however write a variadic function that calls `printf()` for every format specifier and a custom routine for your specifiers, furthermore you can make your program call your `printf()` function instead and use the same name. But I would not recommend that.

Comment: Step 1) Avoid using existing format specifiers like `"%g"` which is for `double`.

Comment: Hmm, IPs have 32 bits and should be unsigned. `int` is a bad idea for both reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would have to reimplement the printf function (more precisely its format parsing function). What you can do is wrap printf inside a function that supports ip addresses or do this:

```
#define FMT_IP "%d.%d.%d.%d"
#define FMT_IP_ARG(ip) getA(ip), getB(ip), getC(ip), getD(ip)
```

Where the getX functions or macros get the X part of the given integer representing an IP address.

Then:

```
printf("ip address = " FMT_IP "\n", FMT_IP_ARG(ip));
```

Comment: What is `getA`, `getB` etc. ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz see A, B, C and D in the OP. The question is about to write a format specifier, not about getting these values from an int.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify that in your question.

Comment: Done Michael. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a new specifier involves re-writing `printf()` or crafting your own function that handles the new specifier as well as `printf()` and calling that.  Both of these approaches are difficult.

---

An alternative is to use `"%s"` and craft your own function that forms a string.

With C99 or later, use a compound literal to form the needed buffer space.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MYIP_N 16
#define MYIP(ip) myip((char [MYIP_N]){""}, (ip))

char *myip(char *dest, int ip) {
  snprintf(dest, MYIP_N, "%d.%d.%d.%d", (ip >> 24) & 255, (ip >> 16) & 255,
      (ip >> 8) & 255, (ip >> 0) & 255);
  return dest;
}


int main(void) {
  int ip1 = 0x01020304;
  int ip2 = 0x05060708;
  printf("%s %s\n", MYIP(ip1), MYIP(ip2));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1.2.3.4 5.6.7.8
```

---

This works with `printf()` or `fprintf()`, `sprintf()`, even `puts()`

```
puts(MYIP(ip1));

1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for [@chux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34639088/1566221), which is simple and portable provided you can know how large a temporary buffer you need.

However, if you are using the GNU library (glibc), you can extend `printf` with new specifiers. It is highly recommended that you use upper-case letters as format codes, because almost all lower-case format codes are in use and the rest may be used by future C/Posix standards. The facility is documented in the [glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html#Customizing-Printf).

Based on the GNU facility, a similar pretty-much-compatible facility was written for the BSD library. Apparently, it is available on Mac OS X, although I can't vouch for that fact. I did find it in the Apple on-line man pages for [xprintf(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/xprintf.3.html) and [xprintf(5)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/xprintf.5.html).

There are examples in the documentation linked above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change standard library functions although you can write a wrapper function which will accept `%g` and will in turn call `printf`.

Comment: I wonder how you can write a such function. Programmatically calling `printf` (or `vprintf`) is not easy.